# Date range as parameter in SSRS using MDX

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, mdx, ssrs-2008-r2, ssas-2008

I am very beginner in MDX query,

I created a SSRS report which uses MDX query, the report has to pull based on date range. I used where clause and used range like

```
where [Date].[Month].&[200609] : [Date].[Month].&[200710]
```

I have to pass these 2 values from parameter, created 2 parameter @from and @to
and set value in query designer.
Now when I use `@from : @to` I am getting an error.
I would be sure I have to use some function like strtomember or so. Please guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of your parameter must have a string with the `Date` dimension hierarchy

Example where clause:

```
Where STRTOMEMBER(@From) : STRTOMEMBER(@To)
```

@From value should be a string like this:

```
[Date].[Month].&[200609]
```

When you create the parameter set as Text, set `available values` tap  like this:

[image]

In value put the following expression:

```
="[Date].[Month].&[200601]"
```

Note the label is the caption you want to show in report selector. Also You can set these values using a query.

Let me know if this was helpful.

Comment: Thank you, was not passing the value as a string, it worked when converted to string.